# Check to see if a button is clicked on... not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, button, isset

Just a very brief explanation of what a part of my code does:

- I have two buttons that do different things.
- One of them lets the user search through the table/database for whatever he/she wants to search for
- The other lets the user insert things into the database

**WHAT I'M TRYING TO DO:**
I'm trying to check to see which button the user clicked on so that the appropriate code will be executed.

I've been looking around and pretty much everywhere I go, people are suggesting to use isset(), but it's not working for me. Perhaps I don't fully understand what isset() does, but doesn't it basically check to see whether a variable is set?

Here's my code:

```html
<script>
    function show(x, y){
      
        <!-- Do something -->
      
    }
</script>


<form>
    <button name = "sButton" type = "button" onclick = 'show("searchForm", "insertForm");'>Perform Search</button>
    <button name = "iButton" type = "button" onclick = 'show("insertForm", "searchForm");'>Insert Data</button>
</form>


<form id = "searchForm" value "search" style = "display: none;" action = "test2.php" method = "post">

    <!-- Do something -->
  
</form>

<form id = "insertForm" style = "display: none;" action = "test2.php" method = "post">

    <!-- Do something -->
  
</form>
```

```html
<!-- This is the test2.php page -->

if(isset($_POST['sButton'])){
   
    <!-- Do something -->

}
else{
   
    <!-- Do something -->

}
```

To test it, I had the if statement print "Checked" and the else print "Not checked". When I run my code, it prints "Not checked". What am I doing wrong and what should I be doing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you now able to determine which button was clicked by checking the values of `x` and `y` in the `show` function?

Comment: If you give the buttons a name, the one that's clicked will be submitted along with the form. Alternatively, the listener can pass the button's name to the function using `show("searchForm", "insertForm", this.name)`. Why are the buttons in a form at all?

Comment: @sfletche Ummm I think so? My buttons work the way I want it to now, so I think it's fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing your buttons `sButton` or `iButton` into test2.php because your second and third form do not have them as input. Only inputs inside each particular form will be submitted. and your form that has the buttons has no action only the buttons call the JS function.

What I suggest you do is to add hidden fields for each form that you are submitting to test2.php as follows:

```
<form id = "searchForm" value "search" style = "display: none;" action = "test2.php" method = "post">
     <input  type="hidden" name = "sButton" value="sButton" />
    <!-- Do something -->

</form>

<form id = "insertForm" style = "display: none;" action = "test2.php" method = "post">
    <input  type="hidden" name = "iButton" value="iButton" />
    <!-- Do something -->

</form>
```

This way your test2.php should work.

Answer (score 1):

Add an

```html
<input type="hidden" name="sButton" />
```

into the search form, and a

```html
<input type="hidden" name="iButton" />
```

into the insert form.

After that. You need to submit the (selected) form in the show(...) javascript function

Answer (score 1):

Use [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this):

```
onclick = 'show(this.name, "searchForm", "insertForm");'
```

---

Example:

```
<button name = "sButton" type = "button" onclick = 'show(this.name, "searchForm", "insertForm");'>Perform Search</button>


function show(name, x, y){

    alert(name);

   if(name === "sButton"){
   do this....
   }
}
```

Output:

```
sButton
```

---

DEMO

http://codepen.io/tuga/pen/RPNaXY

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but I don't see why the buttons are in a form at all. Consider attaching the listeners dynamically, adding a name or ID to the buttons so you can tell which one was clicked then hide or show the forms depending on which was clicked:

```
// The buttons don't seem to need to be in a form, so use some other
// container so you don't need to worry about a useless form being
// submitted
<div id="buttonContainer">
  <button id="searchButton">Perform search</button>
  <button id="insertButton">Insert data</button>
</div>

// Forms for testing
<form id="searchForm"><input value="search"></form>
<form id="insertForm"><input value="insert"></form>
```

and the code:

```
<script>

// Hide and show forms depending on which button was clicked using the
// button's ID
function showForm(event) {

  // If the search button was clicked, show the search form and hide the
  // input form
  if (/search/.test(this.id)) {
    document.getElementById('searchForm').style.display = '';
    document.getElementById('insertForm').style.display = 'none';

  // If the insert button was clicked, do the opposite
  } else {
    document.getElementById('searchForm').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('insertForm').style.display = '';
  }
}

// Attach listeners to the buttons
window.onload = function() {
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('#searchButton, #insertButton'),
    function(button) {
      button.addEventListener('click', showForm, false);
    }
  );

  // Hide the forms
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('#searchForm, #insertForm'),
    function(form) {
      form.style.display = 'none';
    }
  );
}

</script>
```

Comment: I think I was looking for how to create buttons online and a few of the examples/tutorials I saw had them inside the forms. Thanks for the help!